# Access React Context via function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-context

I am currently developing a package, which gives my React-widget responsiveness. The problem is, that the responsiveness does not depends on the viewport-width but on on the width of the widget-container-element.

Currently I am wrapping my `<App>` with a `<ResponsiveProvider>`. This provider subscribes to the `windows.resize` event and stores the format into the context's value.

All children elements get re-rendered if the format changes. That's fine.

Now, for show/hide components based on the current widget format, I just could implement a component, which accesses this context with `contextType`.

But I need a function, which I can use in any place of my application like: `ResponsiveUtil.isSmall()` or `ResponsiveUtil.getCurrentFormat()`.

What would be the best approach to make the information (format) accessable via a function?

*Thanks*

Comment: I dont know for sure of if this can work, but the `useContext` hook comes to mind. Tho I dont even know if hooks are in RN yet.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this would be the *best* approach, but it will work.  You can set up a global event listener that will be dispatched each time the format changes in your component.  I found a package [here](https://github.com/meinto/react-native-event-listeners) for the global events, but it wouldn't be hard to write your own either.  Using `react-native-event-listeners`, it would look something like:

**ResponsiveUtil.js**

```
import { EventRegister } from 'react-native-event-listeners';

let format = {};

EventRegister.addEventListener('responsive-format-changed', data => {
    format = data;
});

const ResponsiveUtils = {
    getCurrentFormat() {
        return Object.assign({}, format);
    },
    isSmall() {
        //isSmall logic
    }
};

export default ResponsiveUtils;
```

Then, in your `<ResponsiveProvider>`, during the `resize` event, dispatch the new format when you update the context

**ResponsiveProvider.js**

```
import { EventRegister } from 'react-native-event-listeners';
//...Other component code
window.resize = () => {
    let format = calculateNewFormat();
    //update context...
    //dispatch new format
    EventRegister.emit('responsive-format-changed', format);
};
```

Comment: Hi! I had a similiar approach: I made the ResponsiveUtil to a Singleton and used it from the ResponsiveProvider and my components. This worked well but: The components do not re-render if they are not using the ResponsiveContext. So if a sete the static contextType in component (what I want to avoid), the components are re-rendering if the format-changes and can access the format via ResponsiveUtil.xy(). But if I remove the contextType, the components are not re-rendering.